# wrong number of template arguments (3, should be at least 1)

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

This error message confuses me, because last time I checked, 3 was at least 1.

```
template<class T, long... i>
struct S
{};

template<class... T>
long xor_fold(T&&... flags)
{
    return (flags ^ ... ^ 0);
}


template<long... lhs, bool dummy, long... rhs>
concept test = xor_fold(lhs...) == xor_fold(rhs...);

template<long... lhs, class L, long... rhs, class R>
requires test<lhs..., false, rhs...>
        bool operator+(S<L, lhs...>, S<R, rhs...>){return true;}

int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (3, should be at least 1)  
  132 | requires test  
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: provided for 'template concept test'
  129 | concept test = f(lhs...) == f(rhs...);
      |         ^~~~
```

The overloaded operator should only be valid, if the two operands meet the requirements specified in the concept.

As requested, my compiler version is:

> g++ --version
> g++ (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project) 10.1.0

Comment: as the main issue seems to be a confusing error message you should include the compiler version

Comment: actually clangs response isnt very helpful either: https://godbolt.org/z/zaeaYK

Comment: _"wrong number of template arguments (3, should be at least 1)"_ 

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 updated.

Comment: I'd `static_assert( 3 >= 1);` just to be sure :P

Comment: Looks like its something up with the compiler. MSVC works fine.